# Update calendar 'start of week' from phones system calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

A user is able to set their custom start day of the week in their phone like [this](https://www.imore.com/how-to-set-calendar-start-day-week-iphone-ipad). Coupled with this different cultures have different days to start the week:

**Australia, UK**: Sunday, Monday, ..., Saturday

**China**: Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday

This means that when developing a calendar functionality we might have many different days of the week to start our calendar from (left to right) to make the user experience optimal.

[image]

We can customise a calendar to have a specific starting day of the week:

```
var customCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
customCalendar.firstWeekday = 3
```

The problem comes with updating my custom calendar to the user's system calendar.

Does this happen automatically when I use Calender (pulling from the user's phone) or do I need to do something custom?

Currently there is very little information that explicitly says whether something manual needs to be done to account for this. Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Calendar.current` and don't explicitly change its locale or its `firstWeekday` property then the calendar's `firstWeekday` property will automatically be appropriate for the user's device settings.

Code your logic based on that property value and you will be showing the correct results (assuming no bugs in your code of course).

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I knew it should be easy but didn't know explicitly that this would be the case.

Comment: If you want to prove it to yourself, put some code in an app that prints `firstWeekday` each time the app comes to the foreground. Now run the app and look at the output. Then go to Settings and change your locale and make other calendar changes. Go back to your test app and see the updated output.

Comment: @rmaddy not sure if this has changed but it seems that `Calendar.current` is the locale's calendar rather than the default calendar of the user set in my device. In my locale, the weekday starts on Sunday, in my settings I set it to Monday .. however when I print `Calendar.current.firstWeekday` on entering the app's foreground, it says `1` which is Sunday.